# retrieve instantiated objects from hashmap

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I really didn't want to resort to asking, however I'm at a dead end. I'm trying to build an array of objects stored within a hashmap into a single array. I'm building a minecraft plugin, and I need to be able to do this in order to reset all players to their natural state. However, for whatever reason, I can't seem to actually parse the Spectator[] array into individual pieces.

The goal is simply to allow more than 1 person to spectate. Here's my code:

```
public class EagleEye extends JavaPlugin implements Listener{

public HashMap<Spectatee, Spectator[]> spec = new HashMap(Spectatee, Spectator[]);
public HashMap<Spectatee, Spectator[]> orinven = new HashMap<Spectatee, Spectator[]>;
public HashMap<Spectatee, Spectator[]> eeinven = new HashMap<Spectatee, Spectator[]>;

@Override
public void onEnable()
{
    //TODO:Who knows.
}
@Override
public void onDisable()
{
    //TODO:Spec off any players being spectated and spectating.

    Spectator[] frickinhell = spec.get(key)); 
    //Creates a master list of all spectators by uuid
    for(Spectator spec : spec.get(Spectator.class))
    {
        master.add(spec);
    }
    for(Object spec : master.toArray())
    {
        //Verify the player is online
        if(Bukkit.getPlayer(master)
            {
            //Verify the player is still spectating
            if(tators.get(uuid) == true)
            {
                //Stop spectating
                tators.put(uuid, false);
            }

        }

    }

}
```

I understand that much of this code is broken. However, my main concern is taking Spectator[] stored within all instances of Spectators[] stored within the hashmap and resetting their values to their defaults. Once I can access each individual instance of each object itself, I can reset their respective values using setters.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `spec.get(Spectator.class)`, `Spectator.class` doesn't match the type of your key, which is `Spectatee`. Therefore, it returns null.

You should pass an instance of `Spectatee` to `spec.get()` if you want to have a chance of getting a non-null value.

If you want to collect all the Spectators regardless of their key, you can iterate over the values of the Map :

```
for (Spectator[] value : spec.values())
    for(Spectator spec : value)
    {
        master.add(spec);
    }
```

Comment: you sir are a miracle worker and if I could upvote you, I would. Thank you for your help.